# How to create a 16 x 12 matrix with numbers 1 to 4 with several restrictions (as defined in the text)?

Tags: matlab, matrix, random

I am confronted with a challenging task. I need to create a matrix with 16 rows and 12 columns. The matrix contains the numbers 1, 2, 3, and 4 in a pseudorandomized order. The challenge for me is to distribute the numbers in a counterbalanced way: i.e. each number has to occur in each column 4 times and in each row 3 times while the order of the numbers needs to differ across rows.
An example for a 8 x 8 matrix I created manually for a better illustration how the final result should look like.

```
1 2 3 4 4 3 2 1;    
4 3 2 1 3 1 4 2;    
3 1 4 2 2 4 1 3;    
2 4 1 3 1 2 3 4;    
2 1 3 4 3 2 4 1;    
1 4 2 3 2 1 3 4;    
4 3 1 2 1 4 2 3;     
3 2 4 1 4 3 1 2;
```

Does someone has an idea how to approach the solution via a MATLAB code for a 16 x 12 matrix with numbers 1 to 4 with the restrictions defined above?

Comment: Do you create your 8x8 matrix in matlab? So can you show the code?

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to enumerate all of the possible solutions quickly, so brute force is probably out. You can try generating random permutations until the constraints are satisfied, but that could take a while. It's probably going to take a backtracking algorithm to come up with a solution in a reasonable amount of time. I assume you need to do this more than once, right?

Comment: And does it need to be uniformly sampled?

Comment: Maybe you can approach it that way: You start for example with 1 and initialize A = ones(16,12), B = zeros(16,12). The matrix A will now indicate the possible locations. (At the beginning every location is possible). B will be your output. Now you pick randomly one element of A which is not 0 and write at its location the number 1 inside B. After this you set the respective value of A equal to zero as this is not a possible location anymore. You also have to check whether any row/column of A has enough 1's. If that is the case you set all the respective values inside the...

Comment: ...row or column of A equal to zero. Now you go ahead and pick the next non-zero element of A randomly and fill B until every row of B has 4 times a 1/ every column has 3 times 1. Note that it's imposiible that there are more/less 1's in any row/column.

Comment: After that you set A = ones(16,12). But now before you start writing your 2's into B you set all entries of A equal zero where the respective value of B is not zero any more. This way you can fill your matrix pseudorandomly while staying inside your constraints.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your comments and replies.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your comments and replies. @  Mikhail_Sam: The example I created by myself without programming. So, i cannot provide a code for that. @ beaker: I do not need to create this particular matrix more than once. However, I like to have a code as I will need to create similar matrices (i.e. different size but similar constraints in the more or less near future). @ sascha: I am not sure what is meant by uniformly sampled? @ StefanM: thanks a lot for your inspiration. I try to translate your idea into a code and will update on that asap.

Comment: @annew Uniformly sampling means: every possible solution has an equal chance of beeing returned by some function. The most simple (infeasible) approach beeing: generate all possible solutions and select one randomly. Without beeing uniform, an algorithm will return a solution, but some solutions are more likely to be returned than others. **Uniform sampling is hard!**. thht's solution is **not** sampling uniformly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kind of brute forcing, i.e. generating new rows and adding them if they fit or discarding them if they do not until all the necessary rows are created takes 30 - 120s on my machine:

```
%% set vars....
original_interval = 1:4;
repeat_per_row = 3;
repeat_per_col = 4;

n_rows = 16;

%% first create an example row....
original_row = repmat(original_interval, 1, repeat_per_row);

%% now we create the matrix....
final_matrix = zeros(n_rows, length(original_row));

show_every_iteration = 10000;

n = 1;

rows_done = 0;

while rows_done ~= n_rows  % we repeat this here until the matrix is full...
  if mod(n, show_every_iteration) == 0
    fprintf('We have %d rows\n', rows_done);
  end %if

  n = n + 1;

  new_row = original_row(randperm(length(original_row))); % this create one random permuation of the original_row

  if isempty(final_matrix) || ~ismember(new_row, final_matrix, 'rows') % if the new row is not already present in the final matrix
    final_matrix(rows_done+1, :) = new_row; % add it

    for i = 1:length(original_interval) % now we see if it still valid....
      tmp = sum(final_matrix == original_interval(i), 1); % how often is this number present in each col?
      if max(tmp) > repeat_per_col % if it is not valid anymore
        final_matrix(rows_done + 1, :) = 0; % remove the last row
        continue;
      end %if
    end %for
  end %if

  if sum(final_matrix(rows_done+1, :)) > 0
    rows_done = rows_done + 1;
  end %if

end %for

%% retranspose final matrix....
final_matrix = final_matrix';
```

I am sure this could be optimized further...

Comment: Thanks thht. By not using the last step of your code (i.e. 'retranspose final matrix') this gives me exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much. I appreciate your help a lot.